# How to Check if all Check-boxes are Unchecked with jQuery icheck plugin.

Tags: jquery, icheck

In Short I want to Check if all check-boxes on my table are Unchecked. If yes I will perform an action.

But I am using jQuery **[iCheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/)** plugin and I didn't find/understand how to do this. They have couple of Call Backs and Methods but I am not sure how to use this to check if all my check boxes are unchecked.

Wanting your kind help anyone familiar with this plugin. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us where you tried to use it? We could not help you if we just write what is already written in plugin's documentation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/koa58o4o/9/

Here is fiddle link

I wanted to show a div if any checkbox is checked and Hide the div if all checkbox are unchecked.

But now if I uncheck one div it goes hidden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/koa58o4o/10/

```
$('.select-users').on('ifUnchecked', function (event) {
    //counts the number of selected check-boxes
    // if count=0 hide div
    if ($('.select-users:checked').size() == 0) 
        $('.block').hide();
});
```